# Exhaustive set of values of $a$ in quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the equation $2^{2x}+a\cdot 2^{x+1}+a+1=0$ has roots of opposite sign, the exhaustive set of

values of $a$ is

Attempt: Put $2^x=t,$ then equation is $t^2+2at+(a+1) = 0$

given roots are of opposite sign and parabola $f(t) = t^2+2at+(a+1)$ is upward

so $x=0\Rightarrow t=1$ must lie between these two roots

could some help me to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've correctly converted into a quadratic for $t$, and hence got two roots for $t$ (counted with multiplicity), say $t_{\pm}$ with $t_+ \ge t_-$. For the two roots for $x$ to have different signs, we must have $0 < t_- < 1 < t_+$.

You've noted that $f$ is 'upward', ie is a positive quadratic. Thus to have $t_+ > 1 > t_-$ we must have $f(1) < 0$; moreover, to have $t_- > 0$ we must have $f(0) > 0$. (These can be seen by just visualising the graph.)
$$ f(1) < 0 \iff 3a + 2 < 0 \iff a < -2/3; \\
f(0) > 0 \iff a + 1 > 0 \iff a > -1. $$
Combining these two results says that $-1 < a < -2/3$.